# How to remove parentheses with words inside by tm packages ?

Tags: r, tm, punctuation

Let's say I have part of the texts in a document like this:

```
"Other segment comprised of our active pharmaceutical ingredient (API) business,which..."
```

I want to remove the "(API)", and it needs to be done before

```
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
```

After removing "(API)",it should be look like this below :

```
"Other segment comprised of our active pharmaceutical ingredient business,which..."
```

I searched for a long time but all I can find was the answers about removing parentheses only,the word within I don't want appear in the corpus too.

I really need someone give me some hint plz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a smarter tokeniser, such as that in the **quanteda** package, where the `removePunct = TRUE` will remove the parentheses automatically.

```
quanteda::tokenize(txt, removePunct = TRUE)
## tokenizedText object from 1 document.
## Component 1 :
##  [1] "Other"          "segment"        "comprised"      "of"             "our"            ## "active"         "pharmaceutical"
##  [8] "ingredient"     "API"            "business"       "which"
```

**Added:**

If you want to tokenise the text first, then you need `lapply` a `gsub` until we add a regular expression `valuetype` to `removeFeatures.tokenizedTexts()` in **quanteda**.  But this would work:

```
# tokenized version
require(quanteda)
toks <- tokenize(txt, what = "fasterword", simplify = TRUE)
toks[-grep("^\\(.*\\)$", toks)]
## [1] "Other"             "segment"           "comprised"         "of"                "our"               "active"           
## [7] "pharmaceutical"    "ingredient"        "business,which..."
```

If you simply want to remove the parenthetical expressions as in the question,  then you don't need either **tm** or **quanteda**:

```
# exactly as in the question
gsub("\\s(\\(\\w*\\))(\\s|[[:punct:]])", "\\2", txt)
## [1] "Other segment comprised of our active pharmaceutical ingredient business,which..."

# with added punctuation
txt2 <- "ingredient (API), business,which..."
txt3 <- "ingredient (API).  New sentence..."
gsub("\\s(\\(\\w*\\))(\\s|[[:punct:]])", "\\2", txt2)
## [1] "ingredient, business,which..."
gsub("\\s(\\(\\w*\\))(\\s|[[:punct:]])", "\\2", txt3)
## [1] "ingredient.  New sentence..."
```

The longer regular expression also catches cases in which the parenthetical expression ends a sentence or is followed by additional punctuation such as a comma.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need to remove not just parentheses. The word within also need to be removed.

Comment: OK I've modified my answer, see above.

Comment: @JohnChou thanks for letting me know. An up vote would be a nice thanks.

Comment: The **"If you want to tokenise the text first, then you need lapply a gsub until we add a regular expression valuetype to removeFeatures.tokenizedTexts() in quanteda."**
I don't really follow, can you explain in more details? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If it's only single words, how about (untested):

```
removeBracketed <- content_transformer(function(x, ...) {gsub("\\(\\w+\\)", "", x)})
tm_map(corpus, removeBracketed)
```